# How to fetch the IP address from the service and pass it to a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

I have a client and server app. client app needs server Ip in the environment variable.

For that purpose, I think to use services but unable to get that Ip from services.

Let me know how can I achieve that?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: serverapp
  name: serverapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: sample-image
    name: serverapp
    env:
    - name: MESSAGE
      value: "Hello from Server"
    - name: PORT
      value: "5000"
    ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
    resources: {}
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 1h"]
  restartPolicy: Never
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serverapp-service
spec:
  selector:
    run: serverapp
  ports:
  - name: serveripandport
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: clientapp
  name: clientapp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: sample-image
    name: clientapp
    env:
    - name: IP
      value: serverapp-service                  ## Need serverapp ip here but not getting
    resources: {}
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","echo $IP"]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 0):

Manifest that you've shared looks fine. **Can you confirm if you're creating all resources (client app, server app & server service) in same namespace**? Please share any other issue, error code or stack trace too, if possible.

Another point: You're inject `Service` name in client app as environment variable. Name of a Service acts as a hostname which gets resolved by K8s DNS Pods (e.g CoreDNS) to an IP address. `Service` **won't give you IP address directly**. If you want to confirm whether the service is actually pointing to correct pods:

- check if Kubernetes endpoints exist against the service

```
kubectl get endponts
```

- Run a `dnsutils` pod ([example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)) in the same `namespace` and use nslookup to check if service is actually resolving correctly inside the pod

```
nslookup serverapp-service
# expected output
  Server:         10.12.0.10
  Address:        10.12.0.10#53

  Name:   serverapp-service.default.svc.cluster.local
  Address: 10.12.1.195
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve pod's IP as an environment variable (named `PODIP` in this example) like this. Just include this in your pod definition

```yaml
- env:
  - name: PODIP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.podIP
```

More info: [Expose Pod Information to Containers Through Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/)

If you need to get the service address from a pod, just follow [service and environment-variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#environment-variables)

But from your manifest it seems you want to access from the client pods to another (server) pods IP. As far as I know that is not possible using environment variables.

One solution can be using also a service for your server pods, and point the client pods to the server service (instead of the IP) using service name as a dns.

Answer (score 0):

When we link any service with the pod then it created some environment variable.

In my case its `SERVERAPP_SERVICE_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR` it contains the server pod ip address.

You can check the list of all the environment variables and use it in the manifest.

```
kubectl exec -it clientapp -- env
```